# Using fork() to find the sum of digits in a number

Tags: unix, fork, wait, system-calls

I'm writing a small program that takes a number in the command line and uses fork() to create a chain of processes that sum the number's digits. So far, it is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

  if(argc != 2){
    printf("Usage: sod [number] \n");  /* -o sod when compiled */
    exit(1); 
  }

  pid_t childpid = 0; 
  int sum = 0;   

  int i; 
  for(i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]); i++){
    /* atoi needs a string */
    char str[2]; 
    str[0] = argv[1][i]; str[1] = 0;  
    sum += atoi(str);   
    if(childpid = fork()) 
      break;  
  }

  wait(NULL); 
  printf("sum: %d\n", sum);
  exit(0); /* probably redundant... */
  return 0; 
}
```

From what I can understand in my systems book, the if statement ensures that the processes are in a chain (each parent can have one child, and it continues down the line), because `fork()` returns the child's id to a parent process and 0 to a child. Thus, the result of the assignment is nonzero/true for a parent and forces it to break from the loop:

```
 if(childpid = fork()) 
          break;
```

Before I added the `wait(NULL)` call, the function printed multiple lines of the sum, not necessarily in order, which I suppose should be expected because the processes finish at different times. Interestingly, though, if I call the program with a large number of digits like 11221121, it sometimes prints some of the sums, outputs my shell prompt right in the middle of them, and prints a few more before hanging there as if in an infinite loop:

```
[nvj]@sun ~/313/sod> (12:15:21 02/10/13)
:: sod 11221121
sum: 1
sum: 2
sum: 4
sum: 6
sum: 7
sum: 8
sum: 10

[nvj]@sun ~/313/sod> (12:15:24 02/10/13)
:: sum: 11
sum: 11
[hangs here...]
```

My only guess as to why this might be happening is that something is timing out or things that need to wait for others are getting into a rut. To make the program actually end (and print the sums in some kind of order), I added the `wait(NULL)` call. From what I can understand, it forces a parent to wait for all of its children before continuing. Unsurprisingly, this causes the actual sum to print first as the last created child finishes, and lets the rest follow in order:
[

```
nvj]@sun ~/313/sod> (12:25:02 02/10/13)
:: sod 12389492182398
sum: 69
sum: 69
sum: 61
sum: 52
sum: 49
sum: 47
sum: 39
sum: 38
sum: 36
sum: 27
sum: 23
sum: 14
sum: 6
sum: 3
sum: 1
```

Thankfully, the program actually ends in this case. But is there a way to make it end right when the child with the actual sum returns and displays its result? I have experimented with things like flat-out calling `exit`(as you can see...), but this seems to operate in a different 'realm' than the child processes and does not immediately happen after the first print.

Comment: There's no need to build a string and use `atoi` to get the numeric value of a char.  (And there's no need to ever use `atoi`; use `strtol` instead.)  Just do `int i = argv[1][0] - '0'` (And validate that `argv[1][0] <= '9' && argv[1][0] >= '0'`)

Comment: It's bad practice to hard code the executable name into the usage message; use `argv[0]` to get the name.

Comment: The `for (i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]); i++)` loop isn't a good idea either; it calculates the length on each iteration, which can be seriously slow if the string is long.  Calculate the length once outside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `fork()` is a pretty expensive way to sum the digits of a number.  You could do it with a web service instead; that would be slower.

So, as a training exercise, you need to realize that each child has its own copy of its variables.  There's no way for the Nth child to affect the value of `sum` in any of its parent processes — unless you get into shared memory, etc.

When you say:

```
sum: 10

[nvj]@sun ~/313/sod> (12:15:24 02/10/13)
:: sum: 11
sum: 11
[hangs here...]
```

The shell prompted you beforehand, and is waiting for your input.  If you type `echo Hi` at the 'hung' shell, you'll see `Hi` echoed and your prompt as normal.  It simply means that your parent process finished before the last child had finished writing.

Before you put the `wait()` in, your first process forked, and exited the loop, and printed its value, and exited, allowing the shell to prompt again.  Meanwhile, the first child was doing its stuff, and the second, and each of those was forking and exiting, and the order in which things happen is determined by the scheduler.

With the `wait()` in place, the child (and its child (and its child (and its child ...))) has completed its output and you get the answers back in a deterministic order.

The last child has the sum of the digits accumulated by the previous child, which means that only the last child needs to print anything to get the final sum.

One of the statements `exit(0);` and `return(0);` is redundant.  I recommend using the `return(0);` instead of the `exit(0);`.